# Pandas merging Dataframes by Date column with non-unique Dates without duplicating rows

Tags: python, pandas, merge

is it possible to merge these two data frames without duplicating the 2 for each df1 date (because non-unique)?
I would like to have the 2 on the first of the non-unique Dates and all after that should be Nan. Is this possible without performing a .duplicate search directly while merging?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.DatetimeIndex(['2012-1-1', '2012-1-1']),
                   'a':[8,9]}, columns=['date', 'a'])

df2 = df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.DatetimeIndex(['2012-1-1']),
                   'b':[2]}, columns=['date', 'b'])

undesired_result=pd.merge(df1,df2,  how='left', left_on=['date'], right_on = ['date'])
undesired_result= pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.DatetimeIndex(['2012-1-1', '2012-1-1']),
                           'a':[8,9], 'b':[2, 2] }, columns=['date', 'a', 'b'])

desired_result= pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.DatetimeIndex(['2012-1-1', '2012-1-1']),
                       'a':[8,9], 'b':[2, np.nan] }, columns=['date', 'a', 'b'])
```

I hope I could clarify well what I would like to have. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have first to deduplicate the keys with `groupby.cumcount`

Comment: @mozway... too late: `df1.assign(idx=df1.groupby('date').cumcount()).merge(df2.assign(idx=df2.groupby('date').cumcount()), on=['date', 'idx'], how='left').drop(columns='idx')` but your solution is better.

Comment: @mozway 
thanks guys .. sry I couldn't find the already answered question which is now linked !